# Filter items of a list to match an input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a problem with getting the innerHTML of an element.
I have a project in Ionic/Angular/Typescript and one page consists of an ion-list with several ion-items. I also have a search box and I want to see only the ion-items which contain the string from the search input.

I tried something like:

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngIf="f(this)"> ... 
</ ion-item>
</ ion-list>
```

and wrote a function that takes as parameter an element and checks whether the search input matches the innerHTML(or textContent) of that element.

```
public f(t: HTMLElement): boolean {
    return t.textContent.indexOf(this.searchInput) !== -1;
}
```

The problem with this logic is that "this" seems to be undefined inside the function.

Comment: Please show us the function you wrote - we need this in order to answer any questions about it.

Comment: public f(t: HTMLElement): boolean {
    return t.textContent.indexOf(this.searchInput) !== -1;   
}

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where you are calling this function from but there is a great chance that it is from some event handler.

Try defining your function as an arrow function, which will preserve the "surrounding" `this` i.e.

```
const f = (t: HTMLElement): boolean  => {
    return t.textContent.indexOf(this.searchInput) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: That function is in an *ngIf. As I wrote in the original post, I have several <ion-item>s and I want that their visibility change,based on the search input. That's why I thought about writing in HTML
    <ion-item *ngIf="f(this)">...</ion-item>
and the f function returns true or false. The problem is that the arugment of the function is undefined(that is,the ion-item whose content I need isn't properly passed to the function)

Comment: ah yes, I did not fully read the post. Also I use neither Ionic, nor Angular. Anyway, have you tried defining the function as an arrow function above, so that inside, `this` is the instance of your class (and not the calling element)?

Comment: Yes,I did,it's the same. The problem is not with "this" inside the function, but with "this" in the HTML. Looks like the HTML object does not exist or something. If I put everything in a click event and send the event as parameter and take the source,it works. But I don't want it to wait to be clicked...